# Quartz job not getting triggered on the end datetime

Tags: quartz-scheduler, quartz

I am quite new to Quartz Scheduled jobs. I scheduled on job with a given starttime and endtime.
The job successfully triggers on the starttime and the recurring intervals but on the last recurrence which is equal to the endtime, the job is not triggering anything.

```
"schedule": {
    "startDatetime": 1664457960000,
    "endDatetime": 1664717400000,
    "recurrenceType": "Interval",
    "messageSendTimeZone": "America/Chicago",
    "recurrence": "2"
  }
```

I want the job to trigger on all the intervals at the given recurrence.
For eg, if I started the job at 28th Sept who's end time is 2nd Oct, it should trigger on 28th, 30th and 2nd as well.

Is there something that I am missing  ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

The endDatetime property indicates when the trigger’s schedule should be canceled.

Comment: does that mean that the mails will be triggered only before the endDateTime and not ON  ?

Comment: @AppleBud , Yes my comment means the same !